# Explanation about querying a segment tree

Tags: algorithm, segment-tree

I am [learning segment trees](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/segment-tree-set-1-range-minimum-query/) (on the example of range minimum query) and have some problem understanding the reason behind the part of the algorithm for querying a segment tree.

I have no problem understanding the part of construction the segment tree, I can not understand why in this function:

```
int RMQUtil(int *st, int ss, int se, int qs, int qe, int index)
{
    // If segment of this node is a part of given range, then return the min of the segment
    if (qs <= ss && qe >= se)
        return st[index];    // this is the part I am struggling with

    // If segment of this node is outside the given range
    if (se < qs || ss > qe)
        return INT_MAX;

    // If a part of this segment overlaps with the given range
    int mid = getMid(ss, se);
    return minVal(RMQUtil(st, ss, mid, qs, qe, 2*index+1), RMQUtil(st, mid+1, se, qs, qe, 2*index+2));
}
```

> If segment of this node is a part of given range, then return the min
>   of the segment.

Comment: If the segment is a part of the given range, then the min of the segment is a candidate for the final answer.

Answer (score 0):

If segment of this node is a part of given range, then you already know the answer for the subsegment [ss, se] (it is st[index]) and you have no need to go deeper.

Answer (score 0):

in the query, you want to find the minimum number in the range of [qs,qe].

now, this in terms of segment trees can be expressed as first finding the middle of the interval i.e mid=(qs+qe)/2

and the logic is that the minimum in the range [qs,qe] is equal to the minimum of finding the minimum in range [qs,mid] and [mid+1,qe].

This is written in ur code in the following lines:

```html
int mid = getMid(ss, se);
    return minVal(RMQUtil(st, ss, mid, qs, qe, 2*index+1), RMQUtil(st, mid+1, se, qs, qe, 2*index+2));
```